# Linking to images in dynamic webpages

Tags: java, javascript, perl, image

This is a little tricky to explain but I will try.

We have a employee web directory at work that displays the employee photo and their phone extension number etc.  Its a dynamic page written in javascript each page has the same layout but obiously the link to the image is always different.

Now what I wanted to do for some fun was to grab those images to use in our continuous build server (this is something people have requested believe it or not), so that when someone breaks the build I can embed their picture in the broken build email.  I can generate the web page link to the persons details page but dont know how to grab the image link from that (there is no obvious naming convention) - I dont have access to the network share where the images are stored but do have permission to embed a link to the in the mail if I can figure it out.

Im flexible with the languages I can use I am just curious how to do this task

Comment: @chanakya, nice idea , you want to show the picture of the person who broke the build, it might be offending right?

Comment: @chanakya convice the team thats not good or not a nice idea to have personal details...with the build success or break notification

Comment: I'm a little dumbfounded as to what it is you are asking... What language are you using when you're trying to pull the image links? Are you sure the image links are generated via JS (my guess it's PHP)... If you can use JS to get the image link, drop me a snippet of the code and I'll gladly help.

Comment: How about you figure out how to get the build server to send a notification to your employee web directory so you can keep statistics. You could have a shame board for broken builds.

Comment: The link to the image is a URL that you can access right? As in, given an employee id you can go to http://.../empoyee_id=1 and that page will have a picture of them?

Comment: @siri It really isn't trying to do anything sinister a quite a lot of poeple asked me to do it and the atmosphere in the office is really friendly - just being able to put a face to someone in I think is useful also.  Also everyone in the office allready has this information if they go to the internal people directory so its not exposing private details, just work details

Comment: @Bryan Not a bad idea, but the email is something I need to do also as its more immediate reminder to the people who potentially did it, as its cumulative after the first break until it gets fixed.  Maybe it is php that generates the page - in the end I just need to get the link somehow that I can encode in html in an email

Comment: @waitinforatrain that is correct, however I do not know how to calculate the id for the image link (it is always the same though for any one person) I can just generate the page address that the picture will be on (eg: http://directory/name=first.lastname)

Comment: @khez, I am using primarily perl but there are other places in the system where I use other languages like c# or invoke other processes that why i mentioned id be interested in any language people may know

Answer (score 1):

The web directory must be making an HTTP request for the image at some point. If you can find out what the details of that request are, then you can make an identical request to fetch the image. The "Web Scraping Proxy" logs HTTP request/responses in the form of Perl code. Set it up, navigate through the web directory to the image, and look in the proxy's log.

Comment: I dont understand, (there isnt but) imagine there could be 100s of employees, im not sure I want to hardcode or store all these somewhere by, id like to figure this out on the fly so if 10 new people where hired it would just work.  Also to make clear I dont have access to the server code that runs the people directory.

Comment: I guess the same sort of thing im asking is if I give you a webpage of a user like (http://stackoverflow.com/users/605696/chanakya) this part I can get - how can I get the image link for that user eg: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/19eed1058a23a9d13c7a5c4ad45baecd?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

Comment: Ok I missunderstood your answer - I will give this proposal a try and report back here